# Simulink - What connector implements 1 input to 2 identical output

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm writing a simulink model in which I would like to distribute a single input with dimensions of 1024X2 to two (identical) outputs.
I guess it should be pretty straight forward but I could not find the connector which does that.

When I try to use a *demux* I get the error "*The Demux cannot be used to split matrices*".

[image: 1to2]

My question is - Which connector should be used for implementing 1 input to many (or just 2 in my case) identical outputs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can attach the same wire to multiple outputs...Just hold the `Ctrl`-key while clicking somewhere on the existing wire.

Answer (score 2):

That's correct, the demux block only works for vector signals. For matrices, you can use the selector block:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/selector.html

You may also be able to use the [Reshape](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/reshape.html) block, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [multiport selector](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/dsp/ref/multiportselector.html). One example is given on [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/254808).

Or even connect the output "Re" to both the "Output1" and "To Audio Device".